# How to accurately check folders or files in python

Tags: python

I've been trying to code something that helps me make a file whenever it got deleted.

My code:

```
import os
from os.path import exists
from time import time, sleep


#Variable
check_folder = exists(#path)


def checkfilepy():
    if check_folder:
        print('ClientSettings have already existed!')
    else:
        create_folder = os.makedirs(#path)
        print('Successfully created ClientSettings!')

        #Variable
        check_file = exists(#path)

        #If statement
        if check_file:
            print('file have already existed!')
        else:
            create_file = open(#path, 'x')
            create_file.write(#write stuff in)
            print('Successfully created file')

while True:
    sleep(60 - time() % 60)
    cfp = checkfilepy()
```

Do you guys have any ideas to continuously check if the file is still there?

Comment: I wouldn't keep checking, I'd just check if its there when you need it and recreate it at that point

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant.

Comment: What are the target OS of your application? If it's only Linux, you could use the very handy `inotify` library. It basically does exactly what you want, in a very efficient way.

Comment: I use Windows 10

Comment: You can try with `watchdog` then. It's a cross-library platform, and you can find its doc at https://python-watchdog.readthedocs.io/en/stable/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Sayse, I would prefer to only check when needed.
But if you *really* want to check regularly, you can use the `threading` library :

```
import threading
import time

def frequent_check():
    while True:
        checkfilepy()
        time.sleep(60 - time.time() % 60)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = threading.Thread(target=frequent_check)
    t.run()
```

Comment: Is it me, or your example does not make any usage of `threading`?

Comment: @BlackBeans I just forgot to write the main with creation of thread. Made edit.

Comment: It's not working, it said: builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'sleep'

Comment: I can assure you it works. I think it's you who made an error. If you check our respective import statements, you will see I import the packages whereas you import the functions.